# Tic Tac Toe: What is the probability that a random player draws against an infallible player?

Tags: combinatorics, probability-theory, game-theory, combinatorial-game-theory

I have simulated a tournament between an infallible Tic Tac Toe player and one that chooses its moves randomly.

Even after 5 million games, the infallible player wins every single game. I know that if both players play infallible, a Tic Tac Toe game always ends in a draw. 
I could not find a bug in my program and I am missing the foundations in probability theory to calculate whether it is probable that even after 5 million games no draw occurs.

Is there a way to calculate and prove it?

Comment: I am pretty convinced that the program must contain some error. The number of choices, the random player has, is bounded from above by $8\cdot 6\cdot 4\cdot 2$ or $9\cdot 7\cdot 5\cdot3$ depending who moves first. So, the probability cannot be that low.

Comment: Just a question : If the position is theoretically draw, does the infallible player make a random non-losing move ?

Comment: The infallible player always makes the move with highest gain and it always makes the first move

Comment: This means : It makes a move, such that the opponent has as few drawing moves as possible ? Or something else ? If we want to determine the draw-probability we have to exactly know what player $1$ does.

Comment: I guess : The infallible player always starts with the middle. Then, the probability that the random player makes the right choice at the beginning is $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: @Peter If the infallible player starts in the middle and plays well, she has a $\frac{380}{384}$ probability of winning against a random player and a $\frac{4}{384}$ probability of a draw.  If she starts in a corner and plays well she also has a $\frac{380}{384}$ probability of winning against a random player and a $\frac{4}{384}$ probability of a draw, or with a slightly different riskier strategy a $\frac{383}{384}$ probability of winning and a $\frac{1}{384}$ probability of losing.  So she does not have to start in the middle

Comment: @Henry A player taking the risk to lose the game is not an "infallible" player, even if this maximizes the chance to win, such a stragtegy contradicts what the question is about.

Comment: @Peter - some people may think an infallible player is one who always knows the "best" move.  What I was saying is that playing against a random player, for some definitions of "best" (maximise chance of winning) starting in the corner is strictly better than starting in the centre, and for another (ensure at least a draw and then maximise chance of winning) starting in the corner is as good as starting in the centre

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The second player has 8 choices for his first move, 6, for the second, etc., so in any game he has a total of $8 \times 6 \times 4 \times 2 = 384$ possible sequences of moves.  If only one choice is correct at each point, which is an underestimation, then in 5 million games he would be expected to draw at least $\lambda = 5 \times 10^6 / 384 \approx 1.3 \times 10^4$ games.  Using a Poisson approximation, the probability that he will actually draw zero games is then $e^{- \lambda} \approx 1.3 \times 10^{-5655}$. This isn't likely.

We could make a more refined estimate-- for example, it may be that the inferior player actually has two drawing choices at his second move instead of one-- but this would only serve to increase his expected number of draws and decrease the final probability of zero draws.